# Corrupted nodes inside an HDF5 file

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I have an instance of a program running in a cluster, the program basically perform numerical computations reading and writing numerical arrays to an **HDF5** file using [h5py](http://www.h5py.org/).

When I try to run several instances of my code in different computing nodes in the cluster, all the running scripts but one crash. The error reported is

> KeyError: 'Unable to get link info (Bad symbol table node signature)'

The surviving script keep on running without a problem. I have used the **with** statement in all the functions that talk to the HDF5, to assure that the file is properly close after the *I/O* operations are done.

Could someone please explain me what is the meaning of this error?

Comment: Are you trying to write data from more processes into one hdf5 file at the same time?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to write data from several process at the same HDF5 file. Should I use a lock?

Comment: I think you can't access the same hdf5 file from several processes at the same time. You can do it only using MPI, see http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/mpi.html. Otherwise be sure to open file only with one process at the same time.

Comment: Ziky you are right, thanks

Answer (score 3):

According to the Book **Python and HDF5** by Andrew Collete,

> multiprocessing is a more recent built-in module available with Python, which provides support for basic fork()-based parallel processing. The main restriction is that your parallel processes can’t share a single HDF5 file, even if the file is opened read- only. This is a limitation of the HDF5 library.....
>
> For anything else, MPI-based Parallel HDF5 is by far the best way to go. MPI is the official “flavor” of parallelism supported by the HDF5 library. You can have an unlimited number of processes, all of which share the same open HDF5 file.

Comment: Here is an excellent tutorial on how to get all of that working: https://drtiresome.com/2016/08/23/build-and-install-mpi-parallel-hdf5-and-h5py-from-source-on-linux/